# Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'dossier'

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, datatables, webmethod

There is a lot of post about this subject and i checked it all.

```
$('#documentTypeID').dataTable({
         "sDom": "<'row-fluid'>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
         "bAutoWidth": false,
         "bProcessing": true,
         "bDestroy": true,
         "stateSave": true,
         "sAjaxSource": '<%= Page.ResolveClientUrl("GetDocumentTypes") %>',
         "data": JSON.stringify({ dossier: "x" }),

[WebMethod]
    public static string GetDocumentTypes(string dossier)
```

I don't understand why i get this error, i did this before a several times.
My name of parameter and ajax data are the same as you can see. There is another error link to this? Maybe link to datatable.net?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer.
Using datatable.net you have to use `fnServerParams` instead of `data` to pass parameter to the web method.